# Unable to insert data into SQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm writing a method to insert a Student into a local SQL database that contains a table with information about Students:

```
public void AddStudent(string name, string teachName, string pass)
{
    string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\Logo.sdf";
    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + dbfile + "; Password = 'dbpass2011!'");
    connection.Open();

    SqlCeTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    SqlCeCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('@name', '@id', '@pass', '@tname')";
    command.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", this.ID);
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MD5Encrypt.MD5(pass));
    command.Parameters.Add("@tname", teachName);


    command.Prepare();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
    connection.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Whenever I use this, it never inserts the data to the table when I look at the contents of the Students table in the database.  Originally I had this return an int so I could see how many rows it affected, which it always returned 1, so I know it's working.

I've looked for answers to this, and the answer to similar questions was that the person asking was looking at the wrong .sdf file.  I've made sure that I'm looking at the right file.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: fixed my problem.  apparently MSVS copies the top level sdf file into the bin\Debug folder everytime I build a solution.  So if I want my changes that I make while my program is running to be saved, I have to set the top level sdf to the one in the bin\Debug folder before I rebuild a solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('@name', '@id', '@pass', '@tname')";
```

You should remove the extra single quotes - this should be:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES (@name, @id, @pass, @tname)";
```

Also I am not sure why you open a transaction for a single insert - that is also not needed.

Comment: What if all fields are strings? Then the single quotes are needed.

Comment: No they are not needed for parametrized queries, even if the fields are strings - in fact you would then insert the literal string `'@name'` instead of the value of the parameter `@name`

Comment: I was just throwing in everything I could to make this work.  I knew that you didn't need a transaction for a single insert. But, if for some reason it wasn't working because I wasn't using a transaction, I wanted to make sure I included it.  I'm in the process of removing the transaction portion right now.

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely an exception being raised in your code; you need to add a try/catch handler and/or debug the application to figure out exactly what is happening.

However, there are at least two issues with your code:

- The prepare statement requires the data types of the parameters. From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.prepare%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> Before you call Prepare, specify the data type of each parameter in the statement to be prepared. For each parameter that has a variable-length data type, you must set the Size property to the maximum size needed. Prepare returns an error if these conditions are not met.

- You need to close the connection before disposing it (this won't affect the insert, however).

Comment: Thanks!  I need to change the Prepare, then.  I noticed that I switched the Dispose and Close after I posted, so that has been fixed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put single quote to parametrized query, in case of parametrized query the whole data will be parsed as required,

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES (@name, @id, @pass, @tname)";
```

Also, its better to set parameter type, size and value explicitly as below:

```
SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
param.Value  = name; // name is a variable that contain the data of name field
//param.Value  = 'Jhon Smith';  //Directly value also can be used
```

Hope this would be helpful, thanks for your time.

Comment: Nice comments, but this does not answer the question.